# Changing source for an iframe inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, replit

I'm using an Iframe inside an Iframe and need to change the source for the second one.

This is so when I load a new page I can load the footer and header without pasting them in each different html page. Originally I was using javascript to "add" the code but it only works on/in the replit environment and it's janky.

**Example setup**

```
┌────────────────┐
│░░░░░header░░░░░│
│┌──────────────┐│
││┌────────────┐││
│││░░░insert░░░│││
│││░░░░░░░░░░░░│││
│││░░░░░░░░░░░░│││
│││░░░░░░░░░░░░│││
││└────────────┘││
││░░░░footer░░░░││
│└──────────────┘│
└────────────────┘
```

The header is the main load page, the footer is the footer page and the insert page is the content page (I used insert because of the amount of characters)

So how would one change the insert page source.

Comment: You should look into using a template system. Depending on what you're trying to achieve there's hundreds of them. Such a tool will automatically generate the finished pages based on a template that can include things like headers and footers.

Comment: i am not very sorry for this veiw but for me a template tool is limiting and will only be better then pure code if the person duse not know how to code

Comment: If the person doesn't know how to code then a WYSIWYG editor would be the best choice. But even if you don't want that, a template tool will just do what you want to do here without degrading performance and SEO scores